# Generators of ideal of coordinate axes in A^3

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So I know that the algebraic set $X$ equal to the union of the three coordinate axes in $\mathbb{A}^3$ is $I(X) = (xy, yz, xz)$ and that this is the fewest number of generators. But it seems that the ideal $(xyz, xy+yz+xz)$ has the same zero locus, but this supposedly is impossible by the embedding dimension being at least 3. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What gives is that $J = (xyz,xy+yz+xz)$ is not a radical ideal.  In fact, $xy\notin J$, but $x^2 y^2 = xy(xy+yz+xz)-(x+y)xyz \in J$.  So we can't use these equations to cut out $X$ without some multiplicity.

Comment: I don't understand your answer.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Sorry, I hallucinated briefly.  My answer should now be much improved.